# What are some camping tips in general and at East Coast Park in Singapore?

Tags: camping, tips-and-tricks, beaches, singapore

What are the good tips while planning for camping for 1 or 2 nights near a beach. I am talking about East Coast Park in Singapore. We pretty much have nothing to fear there, but I would still appreciate any tips in general for campers planning a night out. Tips which would make the experience all the more exciting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

East Coast Park is a nice place for camping especially in Singapore. The first thing is that you'll need to get a camping permit, which you can [book online](http://www.axs.com.sg/phpweb/consumer/npark_camping_permit.php) or at AXS self-service machines. You will only be able to do this if you have permanent residence or a long-term visa for Singapore as the permit requires you to enter an IC number or FIN (and AFAIK, AXS machines only accept NETS payments for this particular transaction). You aren't allowed to have open fires, but there are many places in campsites that hire out BBQ pits for cooking for which again you can [book online via AXS](https://www1.axs.com.sg/NParks/Internet/). Bringing your own BBQ pits isn't allowed unless on specific occasions (public holidays, etc) so that's not an option. [The list of camping sites and zones can be found on Singapore's National Parks website](http://www.nparks.gov.sg/cms/index.php?option=com_visitorsguide&task=activities&id=6&Itemid=73) (and to be honest, information doesn't get more comprehensive than that). There isn't a lot you'll be left wanting for that cannot be solved by a quick trip to a convenience store, so camping at ECP is easy that way.

Cycling is a one of the major activities to do when camping at ECP and the trails are fairly easy to attempt, can be done as a family activity I would say. You rent cycles for a day at fairly reasonable prices (S$6-12).

[Pulau Ubin](http://www.nparks.gov.sg/cms/index.php?option=com_visitorsguide&task=parks&id=29&Itemid=73) is another place to consider camping; feels a bit more secluded as it's not on the mainland, and if you're into off-road biking there are some good trails there. Camping at Pulau Ubin does not require a permit.

Comment: Thanks, I did all of those. :-) It was an enjoyable experience and only thing was the weather which I expected would cool down during night, but it did not happen. Felt sultry for long time till early in the morning.

Answer (score 6):

Camping tips in general are very broad, but I think I can list some tips:

- Always keep your food in a place where animals can´t reach it. Otherwise you will have ants and other annoying things in your tent.
- Use your backpack as pillow. So you have a comfortalble place to place your head and even more important, you will notice if someone tries to steal it.
- Assure that nothing inside the tent touches the side of the tent. Otherwise you will have water in your tent when it is raining.
- Don't use old metal tent poles. If you're camping in a thunderstorm it is better to have carbon (or similar) tent poles.